# What are the effects of clearing the workspaceStorage folder for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I do a lot of C++ development using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10. My development computer has limited hard disk capacity and `Low disk space` warnings are frequent.

After analysis with the excellent `WinDirStat` utility, `%APPDATA%\Code\User\workspaceStorage` was found to contain hundreds of MBs. There are dozens of random 32-character folders (eg. "9731bc4ee103e04b5a91aff76967e74b"), and each of these containing `.\ms-vscode.cpptools\.BROWSE.VC.DB` files which are typically >30 MB.

Can these files, or better the entire `%APPDATA%\Code\User\workspaceStorage` folder, be safely deleted with a batch script on Windows startup?

Comment: you can set the setting `C_Cpp.intelliSenseCacheSize` to 0 to get rid of this cache for all

Comment: @rioV8: Wouldn't that disable Intellisense completely? This smells like a bug (or perhaps lazy programming) that VS Code keeps obsolete cache files after exiting. A new cache appears to be re-created each session. Why not re-use a generic cache, delete the current cache when VS Code is closed or delete obsolete caches when VS Code is started?

Comment: I work with that setting and have no problems. Otherwise my disk just fills with cache files. File a bug report/feature request at the CPP language extension.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you can also try [WizTree](https://diskanalyzer.com/) which scans NTFS disks in a few seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those folders in `workspaceStorage/` store workspace state/cache info for each of your workspaces such as what extensions are enabled, the state of the explorer tree, the heights and widths of Panels and Views, which Panels and Views are currently open, what editors are open and in what editor groups, extension-specific state/cache info (see [the data storage extension API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage)), etc.

I believe you can safely remove those folders or even the whole `workspaceStorage`- just know that that state/cache info will be cleared/"reset".

At the time of this writing, VS Code has an issue that it doesn't remove workspaceStorage folders for workspaces that no longer exist. See this issue ticket: [Cleanup ExtensionContext.workspaceState when a workspace no longer exists
#32461](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32461). I did also see an extension that exists to help with cleaning up such folders that are left hanging around: [`mehyaa.workspace-storage-cleanup`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mehyaa.workspace-storage-cleanup) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.

As for the vscode-cpptools extension's generated .browse.vc.db files, there are a number of issue tickets regarding the space consumption and disk writes.

- [Fix browse database goes big unexpectedly (#9837)
  #9881](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/pull/9881)
- [Closed
  "browse.VC.DB" causing me problems, constantly writes to disk (Unreal Engine project)
  #7849](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7849)
- [Huge .browse.VC.db file
  #150](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/150)
- [Limit size of .browse.VC.db to avoid filling up disk
  #3470](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3470)

As stated in the comments, there is a setting `C_Cpp.intelliSenseCacheSize` that can limit the size of one of the types of intellisense-related cache files for the vscode-cpptools extensions, but if I understand correctly, that type of cache file is not the same as the .browse.vc.db file.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the storage path of the database files. After that, I think the database files can be deleted safely.

Add this to the global **settings.json** file:

`"C_Cpp.default.browse.databaseFilename": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/.BROWSE.VC.DB"`

See more details [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1404)

BTW, you can also set `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseCachePath"` to change the IntelliSense cache path.
Learn more from this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3347) and [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_what-is-the-ipch-folder)

Comment: how does this answer the question?